# tinymce editor using opa

Tags: editor, tinymce, opa

```
import stdlib.core.web.resource

Editor = {{
  base_url = Resource.base_url?""

  load = <script type="text/javascript" src="{base_url}/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

  @client init()=
     ((%% editor.init %%)())

  @client getContent(dom : string)=
     ((%% editor.getContent %%)(dom))

  tiny_mce = @static_resource_directory("tinymce")

}}
```

while running this above code I'm getting below error

Error
File "editor.opa", line 20, characters 6-25, (20:6-20:25 | 339-358)
Unable to type bypass
 editor_init.

can anyone help me please?

Comment: i guess this is not much information usefull enough for people to respond, please ad some more code and your file editor.opa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had not created the bypass before.

First use :

opa-plugin-builder editor.js

With a file "editor.js" like that :

```
##register init:  -> void
##args()
{
    tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced"
    });
}

##register getContent: string -> string
##args(a)
{
    return tinyMCE.get(a).getContent();
}
```

And then you must get a folder named editor.opp

And now to compile editor.opa, you must call editor.opp

ex :

```
opa editor.opp editor.opa
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...now it's working fine...could you please help me how to configure that OpaCms-857df68 in my local?